# Button disappears on click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a very simple `HTML` file (it's part of an `MVC 4` project but i also tested on a plain `HTML` file)
that contains two buttons and some `jquery` script:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id="btn1">Get a string</button>
        <br />
        <p id="p1" style="font-size: 12px" />
        <br />
        <button id="btn2">Get user agent</button>
        <br />
        <p id="p2" style="font-size: 12px" />
    <br />
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#btn1').click(function () {
            $('#p1').text('clicked');
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#btn2').click(function () {
            $('#p2').text(navigator.userAgent);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

after clicking the second button everything works great, but when clicking the first button (`btn1`) the second one disappears.
I tried switching them and changing the implementation of the script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#btn1').click(function () {
            $('#p1').text('clicked');
        });
    });
    $(function () {

        $('#btn2').click(function () {
            $('#p2').text(navigator.userAgent);
        });
    });
</script>
```

and:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn1').click(function () {
                $('#p1').text('clicked');
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn2').click(function () {
            $('#p2').text(navigator.userAgent);
        });
    });
</script>
```

but nothing change.
any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: have you tried this `<p id="p1" style="font-size: 12px"></p>`

Comment: You're missing `e.preventDefault()` in those click functions. paragraphs are not self closing (and can only contain inline elements), and you only need one DOM ready function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not close your `<p>` tags properly. You did `<p .... />` but it needs to be formatted like this `<p ...></p>`.

See:
http://codepen.io/AlienHoboken/pen/kinGq

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a closing `</p>` tag. A self-closing tag won't work:

```
<button id="btn1">Get a string</button>
<br />
<p id="p1" style="font-size: 12px"></p>  <-- here
<br />
<button id="btn2">Get user agent</button>
<br />
<p id="p2" style="font-size: 12px"></p> <-- and here
```

Answer (score 1):

use this: http://jsbin.com/eqawas/1/edit

```
<div>
    <button id="btn1">Get a string</button>
    <br />
  <p id="p1" style="font-size: 12px"></p>
    <br />
    <button id="btn2">Get user agent</button>
    <br />
    <p id="p2" style="font-size: 12px" ></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

default behaviour of "button" tag is submit. so you need to specify type="button" with  like

```
<button id="btn1" type="button">Get a string</button>
```

and code onlod should be like

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn1').click(function () {
        $('#p1').text('clicked');
    });
    $('#btn2').click(function () {
        $('#p2').text(navigator.userAgent);
    });
});
```