# HTML <input> button(s) disappear on click

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom-events, html-input

I am reading an XML file using JavaScript, and this part works as I am getting the data. Here is the XML file:

```
<bookstore>   
    <book category="romance">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30,00</price>
    </book>
    <book category="cooking">
        <title lang="en">Cook Book</title>
        <author>Manado</author>
        <year>2012</year>
        <price>44,00</price>
    </book>
    <book category="drama">
        <title lang="en">Intrigue</title>
        <author>L'amion</author>
        <year>2002</year>
        <price>29,99</price>
    </book>    
</bookstore>
```

Now I use JavaScript to display that data in a table. Also, I added two `<input>` buttons that each have an `onclick` attribute to call a specific function. One button calls the `change()` and the other calls `remove()`.

Here is the code for the HTML page and JavaScript:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // for IE 5/6
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
        xhttp.send();
        return xhttp.responseXML;
    }

    // function to print all book titles
    function printTitles() {
        var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc('bookstore.xml');
        var elements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title')
        document.write('<table border="1"><tr><th>Title</th></tr>');
        for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            document.write("<tr>");
            document.write(
                "<td>" + elements[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td>");
            document.write("</tr>")
        }
        document.write("</table>");
    }

    // function to change the first book title
    function change(text) {
        var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc('bookstore.xml');
        var elements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title');
        var title = elements[0].childNodes[0];
        title.nodeValue = text;
        printTitles(elements);
    }

    // function to remove the first book
    function remove(node) {
        var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc('bookstore.xml');
        var rem = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(node)[0];
        xmlDoc.documentElement.removeChild(rem);
        printTitles(elements);
    }

    printTitles();

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="change" onclick="change('WORKS')"/>
    <input type="button" value="remove" onclick="remove('book')"/>
</body>

</html>
```

When I click the `change` button, both buttons disappear.
When I click the `remove` button, only `remove` button disappears.

Here are all 3 states of my page (I cannot upload a photo because I don't have the rep):

http://postimg.org/image/5lrwf7rcz/

Now, I already searched for an answer and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336077/button-disappears-on-click) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119773/javascript-code-disappears-after-button-click) answers didn't help me. I couldn't find a missing closing tag and returning `false` doesn't change anything.

**UPDATE:** I ran the debugger on Chrome and when I click the `remove` button, the `remove()` function **never gets called** but when I click the `change` button, the `change()` function **does get called**.

Comment: That's what `document.write` does, it overwrites the `document` !

Comment: so I am suppose to recreate the buttons each time they are pressed if I want things to work this way?

Comment: Better not use `document.write`

Comment: No, you're supposed to ***not*** use `document.write`  !!!

Comment: And you're doing ajax, and trying to return the responseText without waiting for the readyState event ?

Comment: I am following a tutorial, like I said, i'm still a newbie

Comment: I found one error, i was missing a semicolon inside the `printTitles()` at `document.write("</tr>")`

Comment: After reading about [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) you should get familiar with DOM manipulation methods [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement), [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode) and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).

Comment: Don't call the function "remove". See this thread for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178016/javascript-onclick-event-not-working-in-chrome-for-text-within-div-container. Also, you're not defining `elements` in there so the table can't be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution so I though I might post it here in case somebody needs it.

First of all, I was missing a semicolon inside the `printTitles()` at `document.write("</tr>")` but that wasn't the main reason behind the program not working.

After taking @Teemu's advice on functions `createElement`, `createTextNode`, `appendChild` and reviewing other helpful comments, I changed the code a lot. I used the mentioned functions and added the `window.onload` check to make sure I can edit the body after the page loads.

XML file stays the same and here is my HTML file with JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {

        // function that loads an XML file through an HTTP request
        function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // for IE 5/6
                xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
            xhttp.send();
            return xhttp.responseXML;
        }

        var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc('bookstore.xml'); // holds the loaded XML file

        // builds a string from xml elements containing the HTML code for the body
        function buildBody(elements) {
            var body = '<table border="1"><tr><th>Title</th></tr>';
            for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                body += "<tr>";
                body += 
                    "<td id='" + i +"'>" + elements[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td>";
                body += "</tr>";
            }
            body += "</table>";
            return body;
        }

        // prints the input buttons
        function printInputs(elements) {
            document.body.innerHTML = buildBody(elements);

            // button change
            var inputChange = document.createElement('input');
            inputChange.setAttribute('type', 'button');
            inputChange.setAttribute('value', 'Change first title');
            inputChange.onclick = function change() {  // on click function for the button
                    document.getElementById(0).innerHTML = 'WORKS';
            }
            document.body.appendChild(inputChange); // add button to the body

            // button remove
            var inputRemove = document.createElement('input');
            inputRemove.setAttribute('type', 'button');
            inputRemove.setAttribute('value', 'Remove first title');
            inputRemove.onclick = function remove() { // on click function for the button
                    document.getElementById(0).innerHTML = '';
            }
            document.body.appendChild(inputRemove); // add button to the body
        }

        function printTitles() {
                var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc('bookstore.xml');
                var elements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title');
                printInputs(elements);  
        }

        printTitles();
    }


    </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```